# Stepping through angular unit tests in Visual Studios with Chutzpah

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, unit-testing, chutzpah

I'm new to angular unit testing and chutzpah. I have everything set up (angular libraries, jasmine, sinon, angular-mocks, etc.) and running but I realize as I'm writing my unit tests that debugging them is a pain using chutzpah because I'm not able to attach a debugger (or at least I don't know how) and step through my angular code. Is there a way to achieve this without ditching chutzpah and running the unit tests in the browser using jasmine?

Comment: You can open in browser from chutzpah and it will stop on the debugger break points

Comment: So I take it that the answer is "no" then. There's no way to debug the unit test using the VS debugger and I would have to use the browser's js debugger?

Comment: yes you have to use the Browsers Debugger

Comment: I right-clicked on the test file and chose Chutpah's "Open in browser" option. I set a breakpoint in Visual Studio and also added a "debugger" statement. But the breakpoint is not hit. Does something else need to be done? Also can the Jasmine test code itself be debugged this way?

Comment: Breakpoints in Visual Studio will not get hit. You have to set the breakpoint in your _browser's_ script debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 4.1.0 of Chutzpah adds integrated [VS debugging](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/wiki/Debugging-Unit-Tests). You can set breakpoints in your JS files and launch using the Visual Studio Debugger from the context menu:

[image]